# Exact short sequences and semidirect products

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence, semidirect-product

In several sources I have read that a group is semidirect product $G = N \rtimes_\phi G$ iff there is a short exact sequence related, of the form $0 \rightarrow N \rightarrow \ G \rightarrow K \rightarrow 0$ (I'm not sure is this is exactly as it is). I am aware that some questions regarding this topic have been previously asked, but I wanted to know which homomorphisms are those who take part in that short exact sequence. The only thing I know is that $Im(f_i) = Ker(f_{i+1})$, for $f_i$ homomorphisms that "make" that exact sequence.

Comment: A semidirect product corresponds to a *split* short exact sequence, i.e., where there is a "backwards" arrow $N\leftarrow G$ such that $N\to G\to N$ is the identity (or equivalently(!) $G\leftarrow K$ such that $K\to G \to K$ is the identity). Do you see how to obtain the action $\phi$ of $K$ on $N$ from such a split and vice versa?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I might recall it wrong, but I think in the case of groups left- and right-split were not the same. I think having a retraction for $N$ is stronger and gives rise to a direct product, while the section for $K$ only gives rise to a semi-direct product, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a group $G$ any normal subgroup $N\subseteq G$ is part of a short exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow N \rightarrow G \rightarrow G/N \rightarrow 0\tag{1}$$
where the first map is the inclusion and the second map is the quotient map.

Given a normal subgroup $N\subseteq G$ and an arbitrary subgroup $H$ we can form the *product of subgroups* $N\cdot H = \{nh \mid n\in N, h\in H\}$. If $N\cap H = \{e\}$ this is an *inner semidirect product* and one can show that there is a canonical isomorphism $G/N \cong H$. Thus the above short exact sequence can be modified to be
$$0\rightarrow N \rightarrow G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 0\tag{2}$$
but we have the additional information that $H \subseteq G$. As it turns out, the composite
$$H \overset{\subseteq}\rightarrow G \rightarrow G/N \overset{\cong}\rightarrow H$$
is the identity, making the sequence (2) right-split exact, with section given by the inclusion $H\subseteq G$.

Now in general, given groups $N$ and $K$ and a homomorphism $\varphi:K \rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(N)$ one can construct a new group called the *outer semidirect product* $N \rtimes_\varphi K$. As it turns out this fits into a short exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow N \rightarrow N\rtimes_\varphi K \rightarrow K \rightarrow 0$$
where as in (2) the right morphism is given by the composite $$N\rtimes_\varphi K/ N \rightarrow (N\rtimes_\varphi K)/N \cong K$$ and which is right split with section given by the inclusion $K\subseteq N \rtimes_\varphi K$. In fact this gives a characterization of outer semidirect products: A short exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow N \rightarrow G \rightarrow K \rightarrow 0$$
is right-split, if and only if there is an isomorphism $G \cong N\rtimes_\varphi K$, or more precisely, if and only if there is an isomorphism of right split short exact sequences
$$\begin{array}{rcccl}
0 \rightarrow N&\rightarrow &G&\rightarrow &K\rightarrow 0\\
||&&\downarrow\cong&&||\\
0 \rightarrow N&\rightarrow &N\rtimes_\varphi K&\rightarrow &K\rightarrow 0
\end{array}$$

Comment: By first map do you mean $N \rightarrow G$, right? Or it is $0 \rightarrow N$?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I meant the first not-completely-obvious map $N\rightarrow G$. Of cause $0 \rightarrow N$ is also the inclusion of a subgroup, but this is besides the point.